# Running mocha test loop synchronously

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, async.js

I'm running a mocha test loop on an array like so:

```
it('each should have permissions defined for each role', function(done) {
    async.forEach(_permissions, function(permission, callback) {
        log.debug(permission.permissions.should.be.an.instanceOf(Array).and.not.be.empty);
        callback(permission.permissions.should.be.an.instanceOf(Array).and.not.be.empty);
    },
    function(result) {
        log.debug(result);
        done();
    });
});
```

When I log it out, it appears to be running asynchronously even though I'm using the `done()` callback. Is this the case? Are my tests still being executed successfully, or is it only executing the first one and then returning a successful result?

Here's the console output:

```
[Tue Dec 02 2014 09:24:07 GMT-0800 (PST)] DEBUG { obj: [ 'permissions!' ], params: { operator: 'to be empty' }, negate: false }
    ✓ each should have permissions defined for each role // <- here's the test result
[Tue Dec 02 2014 09:24:07 GMT-0800 (PST)] DEBUG { obj: [ 'permissions!' ], params: { operator: 'to be empty' }, negate: false }
[Tue Dec 02 2014 09:24:07 GMT-0800 (PST)] DEBUG { obj: [ 'permissions!' ], params: { operator: 'to be empty' }, negate: false }
[Tue Dec 02 2014 09:24:07 GMT-0800 (PST)] DEBUG { obj: [ 'permissions!' ], params: { operator: 'to be empty' }, negate: false }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `eachSeries`, this got me too in the past. `forEach` is the parallel version.

Use like so:

```
it('each should have permissions defined for each role', function(done) {
    async.eachSeries(_permissions, function(permission, callback) {
        permission.permissions.should.be.an.instanceOf(Array).and.not.be.empty;
        callback();
    },
    function(err) {
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it actually `eachSeries`? And when I use it, now only one of the tests executes.

Comment: Ah, had to modify slightly - the assertion needed to not be in the callback.